# PHP with DOMXPath - How to select and count from this html tree

Tags: php, domxpath

**I need to count** how many of these items are open, and there are four types of them: Easy, Medium, Difficult and Not-Wanted. All of these types are values inside the div's. I need to exclude the 'Not-Wanted' types from the count. Notice the 'Open' and 'Close' values have different number of spaces around them. This is the html structure:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Difficult</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>  Open </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Easy</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td> Closed  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Easy</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>   Open   </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Medium</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Open </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Easy</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td> Open     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Medium</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>  Closed</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Easy</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Closed </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Not-wanted</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td> Open </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Difficult</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Open</td>
        </tr>
        ............
```

This is one of my attempts to solve the problem. It is obviously wrong, but I don't know how to get it right.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtmlFile('http://www.nameofsite.com');
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("/html/body/div[1]/div/section/div/section/article/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div/div/table/tbody/tr");

$count = 0;
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if ($element->childNodes->nodeValue != 'Not-wanted') {
        if ($element->childNodes->nodeValue === 'open') {
            $count++;
        }
    }
}

echo $count;
```

I have a very rudimental knowledge of DOMXPath, so it is too complex for me, since I'm only able to create simple queries.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the data in your example, I think you can adjust the xpath expression to this to get all the `<tr>`'s that match your conditions:

> //table/tbody/tr[normalize-space(td[3]/text()) = 'Open' and
>   td[1]/div/text() != 'Not-wanted']

`$elements` is then of type [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) and you can then get the `length` property to get the number of nodes in the list.

For example:

```
$source = <<<SOURCE
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Difficult</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>  Open </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Easy</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td> Closed  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Easy</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>   Open   </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Medium</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Open </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Easy</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td> Open     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Medium</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>  Closed</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Easy</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Closed </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Not-wanted</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td> Open </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Difficult</div>
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Open</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
SOURCE;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($source);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//table/tbody/tr[normalize-space(td[3]/text()) = 'Open' and td[1]/div/text() != 'Not-wanted']");
echo $elements->length;
```

Which will result in:

> 5

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/rJhea)